# Google Datastore: how to set input values to have indexed set to false by default

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have some data stored on Google Cloud Storage. My app using those data and has no problem except the performance. I'm planning to use Google Cloud Datastore instead. As you might have guessed, I don't need to query my data  using any index and I would always call them by their keys. I can set every individual property to unindexed but wonder if there is any other way to set the default indexed to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to set the indexed = False to be the default. You'll have to specify this on every property when you put the entity. [Here is the doc about how to do this.](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#Datastore_Unindexed_properties)

Comment: ["Here"](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_Using_automatic_index_configuration) is something for App Engine - Java. Is there something similar to this for PHP?

Comment: That only applies to building composite indexes, which only happens if you want to do advanced queries. It is currently not possible to tell the datastore that you do not want single property indexes to be built. This is being tracked here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4231